# Persistance of object instances that are created inside methods in C++

Tags: c++, object, reference, scope

Lets say I have a simple class that simply holds an object:

```
class objholder{

    object ojb;
public:
    setobj(object o);
}

objholder::setobj(object o){
    obj = o;
}

objholder::getobj(){
    return obj;
}
```

Lets say I create a function that creates an instance of an `object` which then gets passed to the `objholder`.

- What happens to the instance of the `object` when the function returns? Does it persists?
- What happens if I then try to access the instance of `object` that has been saved by the `objholder` will it stil contain a valid reference?

Here are some simple functions that illustrate the functionality I've described above.

```
void foo(objholder oh){
    object temp;
    oh.setobj(temp);

}
void bar(objholder oh){
    object temp = oh.getobj();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    objholder o;

    foo(o);
    bar(o);
}
```

Comment: Your underlying curiosity will lead you to the joyous world of pointers and references!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is a language *value semantics*, which means that by default types are treated as values, copied, etc. unlike Java or C# that have *reference semantics*. Lets analyze the program:

```
void foo( objholder );
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    objholder o;                 // [1]
    foo(o);                      // [2]
    bar(o);                      // [3]
}
void foo( objholder oh ) {       // [4]
    object tmp;                  // [5]
    oh.setobject( tmp );         // [6]
}                                // [7]
```

In [1] a new object `o` is created in the scope of `main`. That object contains a *subobject* `obj` of type `object` initialized as per `objholder` *default constructor*. In [2] a *copy* of that object is done and passed to `foo` ([4]) that creates a local `object` ([5]) that is passed to the `setobject` member method of `oh` in [6], (remember: `oh` is a copy of the `objholder` in `main`), because `objholder::setobject` takes the element by value, a copy of `tmp` is created, and that copy is passed to `oh.setobject`, that in turn makes a copy and stores it in the member attribute (not shown in the code). In [7] the execution of `foo` completes and all local variables are destroyed in reverse order of creation, which means that `tmp` is destroyed, and then `oh` (which in turn means that the internal copy of `tmp` is destroyed).

At this point we are back in `main` where our local object `o` has remained untouched --all that has been processed was the *copy* passed to `foo`. Then as in the call to `foo` a copy is created and passed to `bar`.

I started noting that this is due to the *value* semantics in C++, compared with *reference* semantics in other languages as Java or C#. If the program was (syntax aside) Java, in [2] and [3] a copy of the *reference* would be passed, and the referred object both in `main`, `foo` and `bar` would be the same. This can be achieved in C++ by using pointers and references. C++ references are not just like Java/C# references, so if you come from any of those languages take time to understand the similarities and differences.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens to the instance of the `object` when the function returns? Does it persists?

It's destroyed along with the holder. But note that your `objectholder` **copies** the object passed to its `setobj`.

> What happens if I then try to access the instance of `object` that has been saved by the `objholder` will it stil contain a valid reference?

Do you mean...

```
object obj;
{
    objectholder holder;
    holder.setobj(obj);
}
// do something to obj
```

? Nothing special happens (except if `object` does something special in its copy constructor).

Comment: I'm going to elaborate on Larsmans answer to the second part of your question. Object holder won't contain a reference, it will contain a copy of the object that was passed to it before the original object itself was destroyed.

Comment: @ErichLancaster so when `bar()` gets called it won't have any problems executing because the `objholder` instance has a copy of the `object` instance that was created in `foo()`?

Comment: @slayton, Ah Sorry I should've made that clearer. It will have a problem. As soon as the foo method runs out of scope, 'oh' and 'temp' both get destroyed so when the bar method gets called, the getobj() method won't have anything to return.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done your objholder you are not "holding" the object, merely holding a copy of the object.

this just makes a copy of 'o' and stores it in 'obj'

```
objholder::setobj(object o)
{
    obj = o;
}
```

if you want to keep a reference to the object you need to either pass a reference or a pointer to the object

```
object& obj;

objholder::setobj(object& o)
{
    obj = o;
}
```

however by keeping a reference to object you are still not owner of the object (if i understood correctly is what you are getting at), instead you would need to use [unique_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx) to take ownership of the object. By using unique_ptr you can sort of pass an object around.

that said, in order to understand life of object you should look into scopes and the free store/stack.